# Binary Search Tree implementation with topological validation

Tags: python, tree, reinventing-the-wheel

```
import sys


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.value} "


class Sum:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.s = val

    def getS(self):
        return self.s

    def update(self, val):
        self.s += val


class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, key):
        curr = self.root
        parent = None
        if self.root:
            while curr and curr.value != key:
                parent = curr
                if curr.value < key:
                    curr = curr.right
                else:
                    curr = curr.left
        else:
            self.root = Node(key)
            return

        if parent:
            if parent.value < key:
                parent.right = Node(key)
            else:
                parent.left = Node(key)

    def delete(self, key):
        pass

    def _doFind(self, root, key):
        if root:
            if root.value == key:
                return root
            if root.value < key:
                self._doFind(root.right, key)
            else:
                self._doFind(root.left, key)

    def find(self, key):
        self._doFind(self.root, key)

    def _inorder(self, root):
        if root:
            self._inorder(root.left)
            print(root, " ")
            self._inorder(root.right)

    def inorder(self):
        self._inorder(self.root)

    def _preorder(self, root):
        if root:
            print(root, " ")
            self._preorder(root.left)
            self._preorder(root.right)

    def preorder(self):
        self._preorder(self.root)

    def _postorder(self, root):
        if root:
            self._postorder(root.left)
            self._postorder(root.right)
            print(root, " ")

    def postorder(self):
        self._postorder(self.root)

    def sumRToL(self, root, s):
        if root:
            self.sumRToL(root.right, s)
            s.update(root.value)
            root.value = s.getS()
            self.sumRToL(root.left, s)

    def sumelementsfromRtoLinplace(self):
        s = Sum(0)
        self.sumRToL(self.root, s)

    def validate(self, root, low, high):
        # Look for iterative solutions as well, probably using some stack
        return (not root) or (low <= root.value <= high and (
                self.validate(root.left, low, root.value) and self.validate(root.right, root.value, high)))

    def validatebst(self):
        max = sys.maxsize
        min = -sys.maxsize - 1
        return self.validate(self.root, min, max)

    def isSameTree(self, p, q):
        # Task : Can a level order solve this. Any non-recursive solutions as stack depth is not reliable?
        """
         Checks the value as well as topological order
        :type p: Node
        :type q: Node
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not p and not q:
            return True
        elif p and q and p.value == q.value:
            return self.isSameTree(p.left, q.left) and self.isSameTree(p.right, q.right)
        return False


def test_main():
    bst = BST()
    bst.insert(1)
    bst.insert(2)
    bst.insert(3)
    bst.insert(4)
    bst.insert(5)
    # bst.root.left = Node(34) # Mess up the tree
    # bst.insert(2)
    # bst.insert(3)
    # bst.insert(4)
    # bst.insert(5)
    # bst.sumelementsfromRtoLinplace()
    # bst.inorder()
    bst1 = BST()
    bst1.insert(1)
    bst1.insert(2)
    bst1.insert(3)
    bst1.insert(4)
    bst1.insert(5)

    print('Same tree : ', bst.isSameTree(bst.root, bst1.root))
    print("Valid Tree : ", bst.validatebst())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```

P.S : I had to create the `Sum` class as there's no way to share the same primitive int across stack calls as there is no pass by reference in Python. I wanted to avoid using global variables throughout.

Answer (score 1):

## Coding style

Python has some conventions about coding style, for example `snake_case` for variables and functions etc. You can find these in [pep-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

## `Node.__repr__`

for troubleshooting, this can be handy:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f"Node({self.value})"
```

with optionally the values of the children elements too

## `BST.update`

adding a simple method to add multiple nodes can make initialization a lot simpler:

```
def update(self, values):
    for value in values:
        self.insert(value)
```

It also allows you to do this immediately in the `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, values=None):
    self.root = None
    if values is not None:
        self.update(values)
```

and use something like this in your tests:

```
bst = BST(range(5))
```

## Node

All of the methods you prepend with an `_` make more sense as methods on the `Node`

### `_xxorder`

for example `_inorder`:

```
def inorder(self):
    if self.left is not None:
        yield from self.left.inorder()
    yield self
    if self.right is not None:
        yield from self.right.inorder()
```

and then `BST.inorder`:

```
def inorder(self):
    return self.root.inorder()
```

You can easily foresee a reverse iteration too (for example to find the maximum of the tree:

```
def inorder_reverse(self):
    if self.right is not None:
        yield from self.right.inorder_reverse()
    yield self
    if self.left is not None:
        yield from self.left.inorder_reverse()
```

same goes for the `_doFind`. `Node.find`:

```
def find(self, key):
    if self.value == key:
        return self
    next = self.right if self.value < key else self.left
    if next is None:
        return None  # or raise IndexError
    return next.find(key)
```

and `BST.find`:

```
def find(self, key):
    return self.root.find(key)
```

## `magic` methods

`isSameTree` compares 2 trees. Why not name it `__eq__`.
Your implementation doesn't really use seld, so it might make more sense to transfer it to `Node` to compare subtrees

`Node.__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if other is None:
        return False
    return (
        self.value == other.value
        and self.left == other.left
        and self.right == other.right
    )
```

`BST.__eq__`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.root == other.root
```

You can easily implement the `Iterator` protocol on `BST`:

```
__iter__ = inorder
```

and `reversed`:

```
__reversed__ = inorder_reverse
```

## Sum

You don't need the `Sum` class, you can just pass on a value. Also this method seems more appropriate under the `Node` class:

```
def sumRToL(self, partial_sum=0):
    if self.right is not None:
        partial_sum = self.right.sumRToL(partial_sum)
    self.value += partial_sum
    if self.left is not None:
        self.left.sumRTol(self.value)
    return self.value
```

Using this on mutable `value`s might have strange effects.

on `BST`:

```
def sumelementsfromRtoLinplace(self):
    if self.root is not None:
        self.root.sumRToL()
```

## validate

checking whether your tree is valid can become very easy via the iterator we just implemented. Using `pairwise` from the itertool recipes:

```
def validate(self):
    return all(a > b for a, b in pairwise(self)) # or self.inorder() for extra clarity
```

## testing

These unit tests can be better done in another file, importing this file, and using one of the unit test frameworks. I'm quite happy with `py.test`.

```
import pytest

from binary_tree import BST


def test_order():
    bst = BST(range(10))
    assert [item.value for item in bst.inorder()] == list(range(10))
    assert [item.value for item in bst] == list(range(10))


def test_reverse():
    bst = BST(range(10))

    items = list(reversed(range(10)))
    assert [item.value for item in bst.inorder_reverse()] == items
    assert [item.value for item in reversed(bst)] == items


def test_equal():
    bst1 = BST(range(5))
    bst2 = BST(range(5))
    bst3 = BST(range(6))
    bst4 = BST(range(-3, 6))

    assert bst1 == bst2
    assert bst1 != bst3
    assert bst3 != bst1
    assert bst1 != bst4
...
```

---

## total code

```
from general_tools.itertools_recipes import pairwise


class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.left: Node = None
        self.right: Node = None
        self.value = value

    def inorder(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.inorder()
        yield self
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.inorder()

    def inorder_reverse(self):
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.inorder_reverse()
        yield self
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.inorder_reverse()

    def preorder(self):
        yield self
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.inorder()
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.inorder()

    def postorder(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            yield from self.left.inorder()
        if self.right is not None:
            yield from self.right.inorder()
        yield self

    def find(self, key):
        if self.value == key:
            return self
        next = self.right if self.value < key else self.left
        if next is None:
            return None  # or raise IndexError
        return next.find(key)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return False
        return (
            self.value == other.value
            and self.left == other.left
            and self.right == other.right
        )

    def sumRToL(self, partial_sum=0):
        if self.right is not None:
            partial_sum = self.right.sumRToL(partial_sum)
        self.value += partial_sum
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.sumRTol(self.value)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.value} "

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node({self.value})"


class BST:
    def __init__(self, values=None):
        self.root: Node = None
        if values is not None:
            self.update(values)

    def insert(self, key):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(key)
            return
        curr = self.root
        parent = None
        while curr and curr.value != key:
            parent, curr = curr, curr.right if curr.value < key else curr.left
        if parent is not None:
            if parent.value < key:
                parent.right = Node(key)
            else:
                parent.left = Node(key)

    def update(self, values):
        for value in values:
            self.insert(value)

    def delete(self, key):
        pass

    def find(self, key):
        return self.root.find(key)

    def inorder(self):
        return self.root.inorder()

    def inorder_reverse(self):
        return self.root.inorder_reverse()

    def preorder(self):
        return self.root.preorder()

    def postorder(self):
        return self.root.postorder()

    def sumelementsfromRtoLinplace(self):
        if self.root is not None:
            self.root.sumRToL()

    def validatebst(self):
        return all(a > b for a, b in pairwise(self))

    __iter__ = inorder
    __reversed__ = inorder_reverse

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.root == other.root
```

Comment: Consistency & Compatibility are more important as stated in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159745/396865), and as even stated in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#type-variable-names) for backward compatibility,
I personally prefer `mixedCase` over `lower_case_with_underscores` as well